# Не удается загрузить картинку

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

Вот так я загружаю картинки:

```
function loadSourcesImage(sources) {

    function getBase64Image(img) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); // remove?
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        return canvas.toDataURL();
    }

    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        var promises = [];
        angular.forEach(sources, function(source) {
            promises.push($q(function(resolve, reject) {
                var imageObj = new Image();
                imageObj.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
                imageObj.onload = function() {
                    source.photo = getBase64Image(imageObj);
                    resolve(); 
                };
                imageObj.src = source.photo;
            }));
        });
        $q.all(promises).then(function() {
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

Но периодически, не для всех картинок, вываливается такая ошибка:

> Access to Image at
>   'https://pp.vk.me/c837437/v837437845/740e/jErhvWmSCW8.jpg' from origin
>   'https://pp.vk.me' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Как можно избавиться от нее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день!

Похоже, что Вы выполняете кросс-доменный запрос. При этом Вы обращаетесь к серваку ВК, который не возвращает заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin (по соображениям безопасности). 
 Но не понятно, почему оно у Вас только иногда не работает.
 Подробнее про кросс-доменные запросы [Статья на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)